# Select - Comparação de hora não funciona

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta visando eliminar resultados em que a hora de término do evento seja igual a 00:00:00, fiz a consulta dessa forma:

```
select nome, local, hora_inicio, hora_fim, data_inicio, data_fim 
from agenda
where hora_fim <> 00:00:00;
```

PS: Tentei também colocando != no lugar de <>, mas também não funcionou, continua retornando eventos com hora de término igual a 00:00:00.

PS: O campos hora-inicio e hora_fim estão como time no banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time):

```
select nome, local, hora_inicio, hora_fim, data_inicio, data_fim 
from agenda
where TIME(`hora_fim`) <> '00:00:00';
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, porém, como a query está dentro de uma variável PHP, está dando conflito com as aspas, acredito que seja por isso que não esteja funcionando, tentei das duas formas, mas não funciona: 

$query->where(' TIME("a.hora_fim") <> "00:00:00") ');

$query->where(' TIME('a.hora_fim') <> '00:00:00') ');

Comment: Deve escapar as aspas! Em Java o caractere de escape é "\".